# What short story from the 1960s is about future where there are no printed books

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A friend recently reminded me of a story where two children hear/learn /read in a book  about a time long ago when all books were in print, and it's very strange to them as they are totally electronic in their future time.

the story was most probably written by an English-writing author, dated before 1990 and probably in the 1960s or so.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not Farenheit 451 by Ray Bradbury, although that is a 50s story about a future without books, albeit in a very different context.  (The film was 60s, though.)

Comment: I vaguely remember this. The children made a remark how it was funny that paper books from the past were static, i.e. nothing was moving on their pages.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a short story by Isaac Asimov called ["The Fun They Had."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fun_They_Had)

There's a full copy of the text [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110611082819/http://users.aber.ac.uk/dgc/funtheyhad.html)

Comment: I remember this story well. I believe I read it in sixth grade.