# Story about kids and book that tells about good old times in schools

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find an short story I read in a collection about ten years ago. Publication date before 1980.

Here's everything I remember:

1. The story is about kids who found an old book with stories about schools in the 20th century.
2. In this future, kids study at home with a robot teacher. They don't know how to study with other kids.
3. These kids (maybe sister and brother) run away from their teacher to read this book in a loft or cellar.
4. They liked those stories about schools.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

["The Fun They Had"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58943), a short story by [Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov); first published in 1951, reprinted in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, February 1954](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61077) which is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v006n02_1954-02/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v006n02_1954-02#page/n125/mode/2up). From the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fun_They_Had):

> Set in the year 2157, when children learn individually at home using a mechanical teacher, the story tells of nine year-old Margie Jones, whose friend Tommy finds a real book. The book tells about a time when children learned altogether in a group in a place called a school. They discuss what it must have been like to be together with a real person as a teacher, and 'the fun they had'.

This story was also the subject of [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3911/what-short-story-from-the-1960s-is-about-future-where-there-are-no-printed-books) and [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13870/futuristic-reading-devices-story-from-1970s-1980s).

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Comment: I believe this is one of the most anthologised stories ever.